# Are exams pointless

Tags: debate

I just wanted someone elses opinion on if exams are kinda pointless?

I feel exams don't give an accurate measure of ones ability. I have beeen told exams are about applying knowledge but how does one acquire knowledge ?

You can't recall knowledge without memory. How can you say you have knowledge if you can't demonstrate it because you don't recall it?

Comment: I was going to suggest you migrate this to Academia SE but when I read it more completely I realised that would be a bad idea. If I understand you correctly, your argument is that exams don't count because you haven't acquired any knowledge. Respectfully, if you haven't acquired knowledge then what have you been doing for the entire semester the subject was being taught? As someone who regularly marks exams, I can tell you there's a tight correlation between high marks and the students who are turning up to classes and tutorials. *That's* where you acquire the knowledge required for the exam.

Comment: The purpose of exams is to *get you to study the material*. The prof doesn't care what your grade is, it makes no difference to them at all.

Comment: Tim I would say just because a student hasn't obtained high grades in an exam doesn't nesscesarily mean he's not attened classes. At school I received many awards for my attendence and yet I didn't do well in my GCSE's. Your point only means it's more likely I would obtain the grades. Any how you still reliant on ones memory.  Given there is more than one module in a given semester, I seriously doubt one has the ability to remember everything they have learnt in the semester. which is what revision is for but are you doing by act of revision?You are memorizing what you need to know for an exam

Comment: @user4894 I completely disagree with this; as a prof who marks papers, I do take a personal interest in getting everyone I can to understand the material. My job is to teach, not to grade. Perhaps I'm an outlier, but I do work really hard through a semester to help students understand the material and it pains me to have to fail anyone at the end of that effort.

Comment: Passing exams leads to getting a degree. The degree is something you can use to market yourself when looking for a position. After you graduate you may want further certifications which involve studying and taking more exams. Obtaining those certifications makes you more marketable over the guy who did not get them.  They have market-value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If examinations can be justified, I doubt if it is terms of some single aim. I have myself set more examination papers (in philosophy) than I care to remember. I can't avoid the platitudinous : the aims of my exams were to test accuracy of knowledge, to assess judgement (so I looked for fairness and balance in an answer) and, least important, expression.

These three criteria don't sit in easy harmony with one another. What to do with the answer that shows truly impressive accuracy of knowledge yet is one-sided, not balanced, but brilliant ?

If these criteria - perhaps others have better - define the aims of examinations, those aims are only imperfectly served by any actual examination system.

1 The examiner can only hope to assess a cross-section of what a student might know. No examination paper can cover the whole syllabus or module. It is a matter of no small chance whether for a particular student the 'right' questions come up. I have myself sat both lucky and unlucky exams - exams where I got the questions I had prepared for and others where I didn't. Say, two 'good' questions and several horrors on a single paper. There is always this element of unpredictability and (good or bad) luck.

2 The examinee quite often faces the worry whether s/he has understood the question. (In one exam I realised half-way through my answer that I had completely misunderstood the question. I cancelled everything and started again, just managing to organise my material in time.)

3 Then there is the worry whether the examiner will read the answer as intended, understand the exact point the student is making.

4 Finally - at least here - there's the worry whether memory will work fast enough, or whether you are answering questions in the most 'efficient' order (don't tackle your weakest questions first, they will or may well undermine your morale), and the sheer worry whether you can sort out the essential from the less relevant or irrelevant in time. Time is a dimension of terror in any exam.

Because of these imperfections in any exam system, I think the golden age of the exam is over. Increasingly exams are supplemented (if not replaced) by course work. But this, though a good idea, brings its own dangers of undetected plagiarism and undue help from fellow students or even, it must be admitted, instructors.

So, to wrap it all up, exams are not pointless. They serve the three purposes I outlined at the start. But points 1 - 3 can well induce scepticism. I know : I've been there.

Comment: Some good points. I sat one exam where I knew from the course content what the question was asking but it was so badly written it asked something quite different. I answered it as it was written and paid the price. It seems like you take a lot more care. .

Comment: Fair enough Geoffrey Thomas. I do agree with points 3-4

Comment: @Ageis. Thank you, Ageis. I enjoyed thinking about something that I had never properly thought through before. I look forward to your further contributions. Best - GT

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth recalling Fred Hoyles advice to the young Abdus Salam when he failed his Cambridge exams. He told him that the exams were meant to be far more difficult than anyone practically do; one of the point being that exams were meant to humble the intelligence of bright students who sailed through their school exams.

If exams were easy it might implant the idea that thinking is easy, when it's not.

Also, as one commenter has already pointed out, exams are also a technique to push students to actually study and assimilate the material.